# Можно использовать сторонние платежные системы в моб. приложении?

Tags: android, ios, phonegap

Я делаю приложения для Android и iOS, на основе PhoneGap, используя html+css и серверную часть, с которое приложение работает через get запросы. 
Приложение по заказу еды. Могу ли я прикрутить туда платежную систему робокасса, и будет ли нормально приниматься приложение со стороны Google Play и App Store?

Comment: Ну, а если это просто ресторан доставки и нужна оплата через банковскую карту?

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу. Вы можете оставлять любое количество комментариев под своим сообщением. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [комментировать сообщения любого пользователя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/49215)

Answer (score 2):

Если не хотите платить гуглу львиную долю выручки, то можно и использовать сторонние системы оплаты. В свое время прикручивал Platron. Исплевался, но всё работало и бана не получили=)

Answer (score 1):

Всё сложно с этим. Стоит определиться, какая конечная цель получения денег. Если вы таким образом продаёте что-то внутри приложения (внутриигровую валюту, предметы и т.п.), то, вероятно, приложение будет заблокировано.

Я в своё время много информации различной на этот счёт перечитал. В GP всё довольно не очевидно, в соглашении размыты понятия. Да и по факту приложения банились случайным образом. Были приложения, которые спокойно находились в сторе многие годы, а потом были заблокированы, так как "оплата производится в обход Googel Wallet".

Comment: Автор говорит, что приложение для заказа еды. Таких приложений полно в сторах, проблем не возникает, видимо. У Apple, как минимум, фиксированная сетка расценок, которая не подходит для магазинов по продаже реальных товаров. Поэтому претензий быть не должно.